# get google calendar id from an email address

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I'm inserting a new event on Google Calendar using a **service account** `service@entreprise.tn`.

I can't specify the `organizer` or the `creator` of an `event`.
My code is:

```
            Organizer organizer = new Organizer().setEmail("user1@entreprise.tn").setSelf(true);
            Creator creator = new Creator().setEmail("user1@entreprise.tn").setSelf(true);

            Calendar service = Calendar_Utils.getCalendarService();
            Event event = new Event()
                         .setSummary("Google Calendar API")
                         .setOrganizer(organizer)
                         .setCreator(creator);

            DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2020-04-24T09:00:00.000Z");
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                                  .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                                  .setTimeZone("Africa/Tunis");
            event.setStart(start);

            DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2020-04-24T10:30:00.000Z");
            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                                .setTimeZone("Africa/Tunis");
            event.setEnd(end);

            String calendarId = "primary";
            event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
            System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink() + " - " + event.getOrganizer() + " - " + event.getCreator());
```

As result, the new event is inserted, but with organizer and creator `service@entreprise.tn` and not `user1@entreprise.tn`.

Could you please tell me how can I change my code to set the organizer to `user1@entreprise.tn`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi, did you got any better solution than the accepted one?  I really need to know. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you create an event with the service account, you need to [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#java) the user on whose behalf the event shall be created

In Java you would do it as following:

```
    GoogleCredential getCredentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
     .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
     .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
     .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
     .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(pk12)
     .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
     .setServiceAccountUser("user1@entreprise.tn") 
     .build();
```

Comment: Hello Sir @ziganotschka, Thanks a lot for your reply. But what I did if there's many users. I have a list of users, and I go to loop that list : for each user I go to create an event for that user which have to be the organizer

Comment: Unfortunately in this case you will need to build new service account credentials for each impersonated user in each iteration. Shouldn't be an issue if you call during each iteration the credential builder passing it the user as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply, I'm working with about 500 users, I think that will be hard to manage. If you don't mind, Have you please another solution to manage that large number of users in that case ?. Big thanks Sir..

Comment: I am sorry to have to tell you this, but as you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) - `creator` and `organizer` are readonly, so you cannot set them manually. The only way is to impersonate the user whom you want to be the creator or organizer of an event.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply. Ok, so I go to impersonate users.

Answer (score 0):

Do an [events.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) and update the organizer fields on the [Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)  by default the organizer property is set to the person or service account which created the event.

## Impersonation

If the service account has been set up with domain wide delegation to a gsuie domain you can impersonate one of the users on the domain and the organizer will be the user who was impersonated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir @DalmTo, I have a list of users and for each user for example user 1, I go to create un event which have to be the organizer, so the organizer have to be changed for each user.